# Introductory PHP book example of a basic social network Robin's Nest

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am a total beginner and reading *Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, and CSS, by Robin Nixon* and there is an example at the end named the *Robin's Nest*, which is

> Designing a Social Networking Site
> Before writing any code, I sat down and came up with a list of things that I decided were essential to such a site. These included:
>
> - A signup process
> - A login form
> - A logout facility
> - Session control
> - User profiles with uploaded thumbnails
> - A member directory
> - Adding members as friends
> - Public and private messaging between members
> - How to style the project
>
> I decided to name the project Robin’s Nest, but you have to modify only one line of code (in functions.php) to change this to a name of your choice.

I would like to try checking it out but don't know how to.
The example code files are hosted on [OReilly](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596157142/tree/master/robinsnest).
Also, there is an improved fork of it on [Github](https://github.com/MicBosi/Parrot).

Can someone please let me know how can I open and play around with them?
What config do I need to change and if I need to create a database first? I just downloaded the **Github** version and did the following to congif.php and created an empty DB on phpmyadmin:

```
<?php //config.php

$appname = 'Parrot';

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'parrot';
$dbuser = 'root'; 
$dbpass = 'mysql';

$home_url = '/';
```

[image: empty parrot db]

When I access the index.php on my ampps/www I get:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\parrot\init.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\parrot\init.php on line 6
The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

The **line 6** of init.php is

```
$connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this book is really not the best resource to be learning from. Anything that involves writing your own "login form" is **extremely risky** and is not a suitable approach for writing production-ready sites you can actually use.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: @tadman I am just a new guy and not looking for best practice, just learning. Can you guide me through to get this example up?

Comment: If you want to learn how do use PHP effectively, this book is only going to steer you the wrong way.

Comment: @tadman, noted, but still, the example has all the php, css/js files, to get it up, I first have to create a database myself? The DBname should correspond to the dbname variable inside config.php? Do I need to create tables or just an empty db?

Comment: Some systems will create the database for you as part of the set-up procedure, but this one apparently does not.

Comment: @tadman, it works now, but it is very slow on localhost. It is simply a toy program so DB querying and inefficient codes shouldn't be an issue. Each click takes a few noticeable seconds. Why is that.

Comment: That's a function of how your PHP is set up, and how your database server is configured. There's a lot of unknowns here as to what and how.

Comment: First step: Does this hold true for trivial PHP programs, or only those that access the database? Second step: Does any access to the database, outside of PHP, suffer the same delay?

Comment: @tadman, no there is no db query involved. just simply moving from one php file to another. Clicking on *Sign Up* button links to index.php?page=signup,  on index.php, $page = $_GET["page"]; require "$page.php"; so signup.php should load. But that one click takes 3-4 seconds.

Comment: *Trivial* as in *nearly no code* will help narrow down the issue. Don't test loading something that actually has a bunch of operations in it.

Comment: @tadman, I realized that slowness disappeared when I changed the $dbhost = 'localhost' to $dbhost = '127.0.0.1'..why is that?

Comment: This depends on the specifics of your operating system and development environment. It could be a networking issue related to how it's set up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the user and password.

```
// config.php
<?php

$appname = 'Parrot';

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'parrot';
$dbuser = getenv('LOCAL_DB_USER'); // HERE
$dbpass = getenv('LOCAL_DB_PASS'); // HERE

$home_url = '/';
```

These are environment settings. You can also just your strings directly.

```
// config.php
<?php

$appname = 'Parrot';

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'parrot';
$dbuser = "USER"; // HERE
$dbpass = "PASSWORD"; // HERE

$home_url = '/';
```

Comment: thanks, so I change $dbuser = 'root'; and #dbpass = 'mysql'; if this is the default setting? What about the $dbname = 'parrot'? Do I need to first create a database named 'parrot' on phpmyadmin?

Comment: @caltonhill or change the $dbname to a db of your choice

Comment: @Strawberry, it didn't work because the port for ampps mysql is set to 3307 as I have another mysql at 3306. I now added $port='3307' to the mysqli call and it works.